# How to ensure, that request / data is sent to server

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a .NET application, that communicates with a webserver (written in Java). Sometimes we have the problem, that the client sends a request to server and nothing comes back. In such cases, in server log no requests from client are shown. At the moment we are not sure, if the problem is on client-, server- or os-side.

Is there a possibility to get sure, that .NET send response to server?

Comment: Use a tool such as fiddler on the client machine, you will be able to see what is happening with your requests. It is usual that if the client doesn't receive a response, the server never received the request.  This indicates some kind of network problem.

Comment: Define "nothing comes back". Add exception handling, implement logging and apply tracing to find out what is going on. You can't make .NET make sure something gets sent, as .NET has no influence on the OS, the network or the receiving party. This is what TCP was designed for, and an exception will be thrown by .NET when a packet can't be delivered in time.

Comment: Fiddler or just use chrome dev tools to watch the network for starters...

Comment: For example the app sends a request to get all orders from server. The waiting screen comes up and after a while, our app gets a timeout error (our timeout is set to 5 minutes). In the client log stands the calling server address (URL), but got not response from server. Now we are not sure, what kind of problem we have. I'm not sure, if you know what I mean.